# Best approcah for getting the object in the foreach loop in laravel using eloquent?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

I have some properties and i want to get the object for each property, currently, I am using the eloquent in the foreach loop like this as shown in the image that will describe the best..
but it is really not a good approach because if I have 100 published property I will making 100 calls to the DB... and that is not correct?
I need a suggestion and a proper solution to this query?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: question is not well formulated!

Comment: can you see the image, that will give you the idea I am talking about

Comment: Basically I want the object just one time not in the foreach loop, because it is creating object every time  the loop runs and on the contrary, I have to get the property ID, which only I can get in the foreach loop, I hope this will clarify you @Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before foreach you can get all the RentalProperty items from db like this:

```
$allRentalProperties = RentalProperty::all();
```

and in foreach loop you can get those items without connecting database like this:

```
$propertyObj = $allRenatalProperties -> where('id', $property['id']) -> first();
```

Also, you can use array shorthand.

```
$newArray = [];
```

it's much simple and readable.

Comment: Thanks, mate looks like it is a good approach for this scenario, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do array pluck before loop:

```
$propertyIds = Arr::pluck($published_properties, 'id');
```

Then you can make a whereIn query to get only those data which are in `$published_properties` object

```
$propertyObj = RentalProperty::whereIn('id', $propertyIds);
```

Then you can access that object with id if you change array key with record id.

Comment: I know these, I am just concerned about the object I am creating in the foreach loop again every ID I get, take a look at the image

Comment: @AhsanMasood i have updated my answer, pls. have a look.

Comment: bro, thanks, but I think giunashvili solution, looks like the best solution I was searching for

Comment: Yes but that will get all the data..which is not safe when you have large amount of data..Just think once on this again.